# Is there a way in EF core to use a dbContext to generate migration script

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, ef-code-first, npgsql, .net-7.0

Looking for a code first way of using a context to generate the sql script to migrate from one specific migration to another. I cant seem to find this online.

something like

```
context.Database.GenerateMigrationScript(‘migration5’ , ‘migration7’)
```

that returns a string of sql script

Thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the EF Core migrator ([`IMigrator`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.migrations.imigrator?view=efcore-7.0)) infrastructure to programmatically generate the migration. To access it you can use [`AccessorExtensions.GetService<TService>`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.infrastructure.accessorextensions.getservice?view=efcore-7.0) method:

```cs
MyAppDbContext ctx = ...
var migrator = ctx.GetService<IMigrator>();
var generateScript = migrator.GenerateScript("migration5", "migration7");
```

P.S.

Also you can use `dotnet ef` CLI tool which has [`dotnet ef migrations script`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/cli/dotnet#dotnet-ef-migrations-script) command (accepts from and to parameters too):

> Generates a SQL script from migrations.

Comment: THANK YOU! knew there had to be a way.